# how to change array element position PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, function, sorting, multidimensional-array

hey folks I need to sort an array by an specific order, how can I do that?

Original array:
**array ('despacho','noc1','suporte','triagem','validacao');**

Wanted order:
**array ('validacao','triagem','noc1','despacho','suporte');**

It's not by ASC or DESC, it's and specific order.

hope you guys could help me. tks..

Comment: _"it's a specific order"_ What the logic behind?

Comment: You would have to have an array in the proper order to know what the order is unless it is logical.

Comment: try `usort` and define your specifc order as a callback :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would do this when you can just define the array in the order that you want.  But if you define an order and compute it's intersection with the original they will return in that order:

```
$array = array ('despacho','noc1','suporte','triagem','validacao');
$order = array ('validacao','triagem','noc1','despacho','suporte');

$array = array_intersect($order, $array);
```